# Make an python plot from recurring arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that is arranged something like this:

```
x = [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
y = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
z = [2,4,3,3,5,1,1,2,1]
```

How would I plot this up so that I have a 3x3 imshow or contour plot?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter ?

Comment: Is z a function of x and y? `countourf` requires that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) for that. It requires that your data is following a mesh. You can create a 2D mesh using:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

Then run the function for `z` for all the `(x, y)` pairs and plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.contourf(x , y, z)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can have a [3D plot](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) like:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
...
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='b')
plt.show()
```

If you do not have access to the function that generates `z`. You have to [interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html).

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
# points is the original pair (x, y)
grid_z0 = griddata(points, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try that, countourf says that z must be 2D, and while the 3D plot works, the plot is empty (although the axes are correct)

Comment: @jhodgo my bad see the update. You need to create a meshgrid. Without it you can only do scatter plots.

Comment: Oh, pretty nice to see a suggestion with `interpolate` (+1), so this can lead to a much better result! I definetely wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: Glad it works! Do not forget to accept an answer to mark the question answered for everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

If `z` is in fact a function of `x` and `y` and you want a **[`countourf`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)** for plotting, you can reshape your arrays with numpy and then plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2])
y = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
z = np.array([2,4,3,3,5,1,1,2,1])
cols = np.unique(x).shape[0]
X = x.reshape(-1, cols)
Y = y.reshape(-1, cols)
Z = z.reshape(-1, cols)
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad to help! here in StackOverflow, if an answer is helpful, [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it is recommended, thanks!