# X Y Z array data to heatmap

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I couldn't quite find a consensus answer for this question or one that fits my needs -- I have data in three columns of a text file: X, Y, and Z. Columns are tab-deliminated. I would like to make a heatmap representation of these data with Python where X and Y positions are shaded by the value in Z, which ranges from 0 to 1 (a discrete probability of X and Y). I was trying seaborn's heatmap package and matplotlib's pcolormesh, but unfortunately these need 2D data arrays.

My data runs through X from 1 to 37 for constant y then iterates by 0.1 in the y. y max fluctuates based on the data set, but ymin is always 0.

[X Y Z] row1[1...37   0.0000    Zvalue], row2[1...37   0.1000    Zvalue] etc.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = np.loadtxt(open("file.txt", "rb"), delimiter="\t").astype("float")
```

Any tips for next steps?

Comment: I know you said you've looked into a lot of questions, but please take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45273661/5103802). I answered this a while ago, it seems to be what you want, 3 1D arrays into a heatmap.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, thanks!

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar -- would it be possible to get more discrete colors (remove the contour shading)?

Comment: Such as a heatmap representation: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: I don't think I understand your question right, but if I do understood it I'm afraid I can't help you, it would be good asking another question or digging into matplotlib's docs.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar: I mean more of a heatmap representation like so, however, I have data in 3 columns rather than a 2-D array! https://marcinkula.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/f1_heatmap1.png

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to use `arr = arr.reshape(-1,37,3)`: in that case `arr[...,0]` are your 2d X indices, `arr[...,1]` are your 2d `Y` indices, and `arr[...,2]` are your 2d Z indices. Your favourite heatmap plotter (`pyplot.pcolormesh`, `seaborn.heatmap`, etc.) will most likely accept these arrays, give or take a few transposes to get your axes right. And don't call that `df`: `np.loadtxt` will give you a numpy array; none of this has anything to do with pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have three columns with X and Y denoting the position of a value Z.

Consider the following example. There are three columns: X and Y contain positional information (categories in this case) and Z contains the values for shading the heatmap.

```
x = np.array(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'])
y = np.array(['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'])
z = np.array([0.3,-0.3,1,0.5,-0.25,-1,0.25,-0.23,0.25])
```

Then we create a dataframe from these columns and transpose them (so x,y and z actually become columns). Give column names and make sure Z_value is a number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(np.array([x,y,z]).T)
df.columns = ['X_value','Y_value','Z_value']
df['Z_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Z_value'])
```

resulting in this dataframe.

```
X_value Y_value Z_value
0   a   a   0.30
1   b   a   -0.30
2   c   a   1.00
3   a   b   0.50
4   b   b   -0.25
5   c   b   -1.00
6   a   c   0.25
7   b   c   -0.23
8   c   c   0.25
```

From this you cannot create a heatmap, however by calling `df.pivot('Y_value','X_value','Z_value')` you pivot the dataframe to a form that can be used for a heatmap.

```
pivotted= df.pivot('Y_value','X_value','Z_value')
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this.

```
X_value a   b   c
Y_value         
a   0.30    -0.30   1.00
b   0.50    -0.25   -1.00
c   0.25    -0.23   0.25
```

You can then feed `pivotted` to the `sns.heatmap` to create your heatmap.

```
sns.heatmap(pivotted,cmap='RdBu')
```

Resulting in this heatmap.

[image]

You may need to make some adjustments to the code for your precise needs. But since I had no example data to go from I needed to make my own example.